# How can I run the Drupal 9 Webform CiviCRM unit tests on my local?

Tags: webform-civicrm, drupal-8, drupal-9

D9 Webform CiviCRM now has automated functional javascript testing! How can I run these tests on my local?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok here are the steps!

I'm on a Mac/MAMP and I use PhpStorm

**A. Get Drupal**

```
composer create-project drupal/recommended-project:8.9.13 d8civicrm.local
cd d8civicrm.local

composer config extra.enable-patching true
composer config minimum-stability dev
```

**B. Get CiviCRM**

```
composer require civicrm/civicrm-core:5.35.0 civicrm/civicrm-packages:5.35.0 civicrm/civicrm-drupal-8:5.35.0 civicrm/civicrm-asset-plugin:~1.1
```

**C. Install Drupal**

Browser to your new website -> in my case: http://d8civicrm.local
and follow the install step in the UI.

**D. Make it writeable**

```
chmod -R +w d8civicrm.local
```

we need to write e.g. the `civicrm.settings.php` file next!

**E. Install CiviCRM**

Go to the UI -> Extend -> or use drush!

**F. Patch alert!**

No longer needed!

**G. PHPUnit configuration**

copy this file: https://gist.github.com/mglaman/efcdb804dcced6ddc856e9e0050aad1e
-> into /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/d8civicrm.local (i.e. where your composer.json is) and make updates specifically add in your `BASE_URL` and your `DB` location and credentials:

```
19c19
<     <env name="SIMPLETEST_BASE_URL" value="http://d8civicrm.local"/>
---
>     <env name="SIMPLETEST_BASE_URL" value=""/>
21c21
<     <env name="SIMPLETEST_DB" value="mysql://myadminuser:db^88*@localhost:3306/d8civicrm_local"/>
---
>     <env name="SIMPLETEST_DB" value=""/>
```

Note: when testing CiviCRM Extensions -> add this line as well - as per docs:
docs -> https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/testing/mink/

```
<env name="DEV_EXTENSION_DIR" value="/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/d9civicrm.local/web/sites/default/files/civicrm/ext/"/>
```

**H. Install webform module**

composer require 'drupal/webform:^6.0'

**I. Install webform_civicrm module**

-> (at this points the tests have not been released yet so you'll need to clone the webform civicrm github repo):

```
git clone https://github.com/colemanw/webform_civicrm.git --branch 8.x-5.x
```

**J. Get the Drupal Dev tools**

We started with `drupal-recommended` - now let's get the dev tools:

```
composer config minimum-stability dev
composer require drupal/core-dev-pinned:^8.9 --no-suggest
```

Note: reproducing this just now - I ended up having to `rm composer.lock` and `rm -r vendor` as it was spitting out a symfony conflict. Ah looks like in the `.github/workflows/main.yml` file we install the drupal dev tools before we install CiviCRM

**K. Configure PHPStorm**

PHPStorm -> Preferences -> Language & Frameworks -> PHP -> Test Frameworks.

[image]

If running into autoloading issues - things to try:
add the entire path to phpunit -> /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/d9civicrm.local/vendor/phpunit/phpunit as a PHP include path in Languages and Frameworks in the PhpStorm settings - hit Apply -> then check the Test Frameworks page again.

[image]

**L. Install Chromedriver**

https://chromedriver.chromium.org/

and start it

```
/usr/local/bin/chromedriver
To check that it's running:
karins-MBP:bin sysadmin$ ps -ax |grep chromedriver
62821 ttys004 0:00.18 chromedriver
```

**M. Run a test!**

Before you can run a test -> you need to drop all tables and triggers from your database or you'll hit this error (below). Of course make a backup if you have any configs you'd like to keep.

```
1) Drupal\Tests\webform_civicrm\FunctionalJavascript\ContributionDummyTest::testOnePageDonation
RuntimeException: The provided database connection in SIMPLETEST_DB contains CiviCRM tables, use a different database.
```

[image]

PS - Note to self: if you run into:
`Error : Call to undefined method CRM_Utils_System_UnitTests::parseUrl()`

Go into -> Run/Debug Configurations and hit Environment Variables and SWITCH OFF -> Include system environment variables (as one may have included variables specific to CiviCRM Unit Testing)

I'm still working on getting xdebug to work with phpunit test - in the mean time -> to debug variables within your unit test ->

```
$result_debug = var_export($contact_result);
```

or

```
throw new \Exception(var_export($api_result, TRUE));

Also handy for local screenshots -> e.g.
    $this->htmlOutputDirectory = '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/d9civicrm.local/web/sites/default/files/simpletest/';
    $this->createScreenshot($this->htmlOutputDirectory . 'KG.png');
```

Comment: great documentation